# Return multiple counts in a group by query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a 2 tables.  A user table and a preference table.

```
Users
-UserId

Preferences
-PreferenceId
-UserId
-PreferenceType
-Enabled
```

I have a query to get be the number of users grouped by location:

```
SELECT u.Location, u.Count
FROM Users u
GROUP BY u.Location
```

I want to make a report of the Users by Location, but also include columns for each PreferenceType (say there are 3 types 'pref1', 'pref2', 'pref3'
So currently I am making a seperate query like this for each PreferenceType:

```
SELECT u.Location, u.Count
From Users u
    inner join Preferences p ON p.UserId = u.UserId
WHERE
    p.PreferenceType = 'pref1'
    and p.Enabled = 1
GROUP BY u.Location
```

Would it be possible to combine all of these and get a result set like:

```
SELECT u.Location, u.Count, Pref1Count, Pref2Count, Pref3Count
From Users u
    inner join Preferences p ON p.UserId = u.UserId
WHERE
```

Comment: What is `u.count`?

Comment: do you want to show each preference type count for each location per user ?

Comment: Can users have the same preference more than once?

Comment: @GordonLinoff u.Count should be the # of users per Location.   Users may have 0-5 records in the Preferences table.  I don't want the count to include duplicate records because of the join to Preferences.

Answer (score 2):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select u.Location, count(distinct u.Userid) as cnt,
       sum(case when p.PreferenceType = 'pref1' and p.Enabled = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as pref1,
       sum(case when p.PreferenceType = 'pref2' and p.Enabled = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as pref2,
       sum(case when p.PreferenceType = 'pref3' and p.Enabled = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as pref3,
From Users u left join
     Preferences p 
     on p.UserId = u.UserId
group by u.Location;
```

Comment: should I do a left join on preferences?

Comment: I'm just weary b/c if I join with Preferences it will return back 3x the rows instead of a single row per user no?

Comment: @coolbreeze NO, you would get one row per location. That is the point of aggregation.

Comment: I think he is asking about the join between Preferences and Users table which would  actually cross join the matches based on userid first.

Comment: @Deepshikha how does an inner join become a cross join?

Comment: Actually, I think they are talking about the count now being the number of preferences of users per location, rather than number of users. In other words, needing `COUNT(DISTINCT u.UserId)`. Also, a LEFT join might be in order if some users have no preferences recorded at all.

Comment: @Uueerdo . . . `COUNT(DISTINCT)` would only be needed for the preferences is users could have the same preference multiple times.  `DISTINCT` is needed for the user count, however.

Comment: Yeah, I just meant for the user count; _SUM(DISTINCT)_ hardly, if ever, really makes any sense.